# Equation numbering in a book (Chapter.Equation)

Tags: equations, numbering, latex-2.09

I am writing a book using LaTex and
`\documentstyle[openbib,12pt]{book}`

How do I arrange for equations to be numbered as (5.17)
where 5 is the chapter number and 17 is the equation
number within the chapter. I've tried everything and
looked everywhere. All I have been able to get is
(4.17) where 4 is the section number of the chapter
and 17 is the equation number in the chapter.
Thanks,  andrey@utstat.toronto.edu

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You mention that you use the instruction `\documentstyle`. Is this correct, or did you mean to write `\documentclass`? Please advise.

Comment: I did write \documentstyle. If the answer for \documentclass differs please advise. Thanks!

Comment: `\documentstyle` was used with versions of LaTeX up to version 2.09. In 1994 -- yes, nearly 30 years ago! -- LaTeX2e was introduced and superseded LaTex209; LaTeX2e-based documents start with `\documentclass`. Documents that start with `\documentstyle` can still be compiled under LaTeX2e in so-called "compatibility mode"; however, you'll be *severely limited* in which LaTeX packages you can use. My first piece of advice to you is to move your LaTeX programming habits from medieval times (LaTeX209) to the present.

Comment: Please post a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) showing your setup. Notwithstanding what @Mico said, even using `\documentstyle` loads the "standard"  `book` class, which numbers equation by chapter by default. If this doesn't happen in your case there is something else going on, quite probably due to code you're not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in your premable:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Most of your code isn't really necessary, since the `book` class numbers equations by chapter by default.

Comment: Oh I didn’t know that lol, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. Changing `\documentstyle` to `\documentclass` and adding

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
```

solved my problem.  In fact this `\renewcommand` was not even needed.
(campa was correct: I had inadvertently been including a command that was messing up my equation numbering.)

Only two or three very minor other fixes were needed to get my
book document (500+ pages) to compile correctly.  I did need to add
the command `\pagestyle{plain}` in order for LaTex not to enforce a
layout that I did not want.

Comment: This should probably rather be a comment than an answer.